# Mount Docker volume on host but make files "immutable"?

Tags: build, docker, integration-testing, immutability

The integration tests in my current projects takes a while to run and it would be nice to be able to just run them locally using Docker and continue working with the code while they are running. My plan right now is to create a script that does the following:

1. Copy the code to a random folder in `/tmp`
2. Start a Docker container that mounts this folder as a volume on the host
3. Run the tests inside the container
4. Remove the container if the tests were successful

Before I set about creating this script I wonder if Docker somehow supports mounting "immutable" volumes from the host so I don't need to copy the files to `/tmp` manually? To clarify, I would like to mount the code into Docker but I don't like to folder to be shared between the host and the container. Rather I'd like the changes made in the host to stay on the host and the changes made in the container to stay in the container (sort of like "structural sharing" in the data structures in Clojure).

If this is not possible then does my future script look like a good idea or can it be improved?

Comment: Why do you need a volume? Can you just use Docker's [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy) to add the code to your container each time?

Comment: You're right, I came to think about that after I wrote the question. I suppose that would work though. The only drawback I could think of is that I need to actually build a image a Docker file each time instead of reusing a pre-built one and just mount a volume which I suppose could speed things about a little bit.

Comment: That's true. However, if your Dockerfile doesn't need the code to build the rest of the image (i.e. to install dependencies), you could have the `COPY` command be at the end of the Dockerfile, so you could cache the other layers.

Answer (score 1):

You can [mount a host volume in read-only mode](http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems):

```
docker run -v /tmp/host-randomtest:/container-testdir:ro
```

Note the `ro` at the end. You can alternatively specify `rw` for read-write, and that is the default.

Once you've mounted the volume from the host, you can copy the files you want into the container, for example `cp -a /container-testdir /writable-testdir`

Alternatively you could `ADD` the files from the host into the container as part of a `Dockerfile` and `docker build`.

Comment: Note that he wants changes on host to stay on host, and changes in container to stay in container. Mounting as read-only would put host changes into container.

Comment: Agreed, but the title of the question was "Mount Docker volume on host but make files “immutable”?" so I imagined he didn't want the container to be able to affect the host.

Comment: That's true but I still want to container to be able to modify the files.

Comment: Ah, you're looking for a feature docker lacks: the ability to copy files from the host to a running container in one step. I'll update my answer with two other methods.